# net start winmgmt

Tags: windows-services, wmi-service

when i try to start the service and type net start winmgmt in the command promt, i get a response saying the service name is invalid. Is there anyway i can start this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the full service name:

> net start "Windows Management Instrumentation"

This question is not programming-related, please put questions like this on [superuser](http://superuser.com) next time.